# I have two systems in parallel, each with an 99.9% uptime throughout the year. What's the overall uptime?

Tags: high-availability

If two systems in parallel have the same uptime of 99.9% over the year then how can I determine the uptime of the overall system?

Answer (score 2):

`0.99 * 0.99 =` **0.9801** is the chance that both of them will be up (e.g. 1 is user server and 1 is product server)

The more PC you add to the system the bigger chance that either one of them goes down. A similar formula is used in calculating the RAID stability chance.

**EDIT**
If you consider that the system is stable while **at least one** node is up (e.g. 2 instances of the same service) then the chance is `100 - 0.01*0.01` = **99.9999**

Comment: Intuitively, that makes no sense to me. What that says to me is that there's a higher availability with just the one system instead of having two in parallel... 

Am I missing something?